# Connecting hover rules for two separate anchors?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The fiddle below displays an image link and a text link for each corresponding page. Each image, when hovered over, shows the colored version by using css. The text links simply have a border on the bottom when hovered.

I need to make the image colored when the corresponding text link is hovered, and also the text link to have its border shown when the corresponding image is hovered. How can I link these together?

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/sLq28jb4/), or look at the CSS code below:

```css
#chorus
{
    background: url('../images/work-icons/icon-chorus to size BW.jpg');
    height: 85px;
    left: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 78px;
    width: 113px;
    display: block;
}

#chorus:hover
{
    background: url('../images/work-icons/chorus-icon to size.jpg');
    border-bottom: none;
}

#chorus-text-link {
    left: 180px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 111px;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to nest the elements?

Comment: Yes, please show me how?

Comment: Could you wrap the elements in a list?  Then you can just place the `:hover` rule on the `li`.

Comment: The HTML code in your fiddle males little sense IMHO – why do the text and the image link to different locations, shouldn’t they both link to the same? If so, simply place image and text inside _one_ link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a parent element to your image and link, you could achieve a structure like this:

```
<span>
    <a href="chorus.html" id="chorus"></a>
    <a href="chorus.html" id="chorus-text-link">Chorus 2014</a>
</span>
```

And then simply write a hover rule for the newly created parent and its child:

```
span:hover #chorus
{
    background: url('http://georgewoolfe.com/new-website/images/images-3copy.jpeg');
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

--

To underline the link on image hover, add a rule which applies only to the 2nd child of the span (text link):

```
span:hover a:nth-of-type(2) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works however, the text doesn't display its border when only the image is hovered over. Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to do this by causing the css hover rule to act on the other element using jQuery by linking the action of hover on the image to trigger the CSS hover rule on the text?